# Format text file as a table using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file `C:\file.txt` with this formatting:

```
VersionID|VersionNumber|UpgradeDate|Comments
---------|-------------|-----------|--------
1156|3.3.0|2017-01-04 23:13:04.687|3.3 comment
```

I want to remove the `---------|` and output in table format.

```
VersionID|VersionNumber|UpgradeDate            |Comments
1156     |3.3.0        |2017-01-04 23:13:04.687|3.3 comment
```

The output would then be stored in a text file say C:\output.txt

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Ok. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far? What are you stuck with? Are you aware of the `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` cmdlets? You may consider using the `Get-Content` cmdlet to read in the input file and skip the 2nd line.

Comment: How to do formatting

Comment: I used this to read file but ho do i format Get-Content C:\new.csv

Comment: This is not a free code generation service. You will need to make an attempt and show that you're not just asking others to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you requested, import the text file then export is as a "table" format. It exports as CSV. If you need it to be exported as a different format, please be more clear in your question. Thanks!

```
import-csv C:\file.txt -Delimiter "|" | export-csv C:\Output.csv
```

Comment: This is what i get in the result #TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"VersionID","VersionNumber","UpgradeDate","Comments"
"---------","-------------","-----------","--------"
"1156","3.3.0","2017-01-04 23:13:04.687","3.3 Release"

Comment: I don't know what that means, and can't continue to assist unless you can be more clear.